# Threadsafe way to copy-and-clear array

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, thread-safety, python-multithreading

One array accumulates datagrams. On interval or some length it flushed to database.

It accumulates on datagram_received network event asynchronous.

```
class Protocol:
    flows = []
    def datagram_received(self, data, addr):
    ...
            self.flows.append(flow)
```

And flushed by this method:

```
def store(self):
    flows = []
    while len(self.flows):
        flows.append(self.flows.pop(0))
    self.db.insert(flows)
    sleep(10)
    self.store()
```

How to optimize it to replace while with one thread-safe operation?

This module runs one instance of class, but in two threads.

Comment: The class definition in the first snippet of code seems odd in the sense that it defines 'flows' to be a class attribute rather than an instance attribute. That means it would be shared by all instances of `Protocol`. Is that correct?

Comment: Does not matter. This module runs one  instance of class, but in two threads.

Comment: It matters when evaluating the sharing of data among concurrent processes/threads. You need to add a (class level I guess) `Lock` and then use it in the `store()` method to ensure multiple threads don't modify `Protocol.flows` at the same time.

Comment: `append` and `pop` are atomic and GIL does not allow to modify array at one time. I hoped that threre is atomic way to copy-and-clear all elements.
Maybe in numpy or something from multiprocessing.
 
I will use semaphores or Lock.

Comment: The GIL doesn't offer the protection you think it does. See [_Why do we need locks for threads, if we have GIL?_](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40072873/why-do-we-need-locks-for-threads-if-we-have-gil).