# Why this multi-threaded code behaves in a safer way when I add thread.join()?

Tags: python, thread-safety

```py
import threading

# Shared variable
shared_variable = 0
NUM_THREADS = 999
NUM_INCREMENT = 1_000_000


# Function to increment the shared variable
def increment():
    global shared_variable
    for _ in range(NUM_INCREMENT):
        shared_variable += 1


# Creating multiple threads to increment the shared variable concurrently
threads = []
for _ in range(NUM_THREADS):
    thread = threading.Thread(target=increment)
    threads.append(thread)

for thread in threads:
    thread.start()

for thread in threads:
    thread.join()

# Display the value of the shared variable after concurrent increments
print(
    f"The value of the shared variable is: {shared_variable}, expected : {NUM_THREADS * NUM_INCREMENT}"
)
```

This code always print the expected number when I join the thread. But if I comment this code then some increment fails (which is the result I actually expected !).

```py
# for thread in threads:
#    thread.join()
```

Why this code behaves in a thread safe way when I add join?

Comment: When you have the `.join()`s you are waiting for all the threads to finish. Without, you rush to the `print()` too early.

Comment: of course, can you put it as an answer so I can accept it ?

Comment: also any idea why this code always compute the right number ?

Comment: I was trying to reproduce a concurrency issue like this user did https://stackoverflow.com/a/40072999/6865225

Comment: I can understand what that answer is saying but with your full code I always got the right answer.

Comment: Same and I'm not happy about it

Comment: Its difficult to reproduce concurrency issues. Like 'undefined behaviour', its possible to get correct behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens when you comment out the loop which performs all the `thread.join()` calls is very similar to when you do have the joins:

Your code will be struggling to perform the loop which calls `thread.start()` on each thread. This is because once there are more than a very few threads started, they all tend to block each other, including the main thread. All the threads will be running slowly competing with each other with the situation getting worse and worse.

I tried the version without the joins and the last line printed like this:

`The value of the shared variable is: 997692304, expected : 999000000`

This means that the main thread was so slow at starting all the threads that about 997 of the threads had already finished when the main thread exited the start loop and finished with the final `print()`.

The reason that so many threads finish is that they are doing very little (just incrementing a number), whereas the main thread is calling `thread.start()` which is doing something *much* more complex and time consuming.

Conversely, with the code intact, calling all the `thread.join()` methods means that the main thread will deliberately wait for *all* the threads to complete. This guarantees that the global variable will have all the increments that you expect.

Answer (score 1):

`thread.join()` waits for `thread` to finish its work. If you ask somebody to do something, would you then *immediately* complain about them not having done the job right? Or would you wait for them to finish the work before you judge it?

If your program calls `thread.join()` on each of the threads before it prints the value of `shared_variable`, then that's gives the threads time to finish their work. If it doesn't join the threads, and you *immediately* print `shared_variable` after starting the threads, then... you get whatever you get.